# Showing that the Krull dimension of a certain domain is 1.

Tags: commutative-algebra, integral-domain, krull-dimension

I have to solve the following exercise.

Let $R$ be an integral domain that is not a field. Suppose that for all $x\in R\setminus \{0\}$ we have the quotient $R/(x)$ is a finite set. Show that $\dim R = 1$.

I understand that in order to prove $\dim R = 1$ we have to prove that all prime ideal different from $(0)$ is maximal, but I don't know what else to do.

Can someone give me a hint of how I do that?

Comment: What can you say about finite integral domains?

Comment: They are fields. How do I use this fact to prove the above statement?

Comment: What does $A$ have to do with $R$?

Comment: Use what you are given to prove that all non-trivial quotients must be finite. Now if you choose any prime ideal and take the quotient, then you end up with...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose that there is a chain $0 \subsetneq \mathfrak{p} \subsetneq \mathfrak{m}$ in $R$.

That implies that $P$ contains a nonunit $x$.  Since $R / (x)$ is finite, argue that $R / \mathfrak{p}$ is finite too, and in particular is a finite integral domain.

From there you should be able to conclude that $\mathfrak{p} = \mathfrak{m}$.